# Meaning of 先 in this sentence

Tags: usage

人生の時間は有限なのである。全く当たり前のことなのだが、いつも人はそれを忘れる。忘れて他人事みたいに自分の人生を生きている。時間は前方へ流れるものと錯覚しているからである。人生は、生から死へと向かうもの。**死は今ではない先のもの。**しかしこれは間違いである。死は先にあるのではない。今ここにあるものだ。死によって生なのであれば、生としての今のここに、死はまさにあるではないか。

May I know what is meant by 先 in the bolded sentence? Does it mean "former" or future"?

Comment: うええ・・「先」 has such a lot of meanings... https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11147675601

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example (死は今ではない先のもの) the meaning would be 'Death is something ahead of you', i.e., in the future.

If you think of 先 as something 'ahead of you' it would mean the future. For example: 先の事を考える 'Think about the future'. 'Before you' and 'Ahead of you' are the same.

Something can be before me, which means that it is also ‘ahead’ of me. On the other hand, something can come before me, in which case it is ‘behind’ me (chronologically).

先 has many meanings. The proper one can be gleaned from the context surrounding it, according to [this Q&A response](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11147675601):

> 「さき」：は多くの意味があり、文の中の前後や状況で判断します。
>   先 の意味を例を用いて説明するしかありません。
>   先：
>   １．物の先端、最初、以上のものなどの意味
>   ２．近未来など 今より未来の時点を指す。
>   ３：少し前の過去を表わす。

Also, here's a useful explanation from kanjibunka.com [here.](http://kanjibunka.com/kanji-faq/old-faq/q0298/)